# how can i create a chrome extension which shows extension icon in a new tab window same as SocialBro Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

how can i create a chrome extension which shows extension icon in a new tab window, and not in chrome tool bar. 
Eg like **SocialBro**, **youtube**, **gmail extension** are displayed.

go to socialbro.com/download and click **download socialbro chrome** button. it downloads and install the extension. Now open a new empty tab or a new chrome window. you can see the SocialBro icon (48X48) at the center of the window page.

my requirement is to create an extension in the same way

Answer (score 0):

You want to open a "pinned" tab. You can see how it looks by right clicking right now on your stackoverflow tab and clicking "Pin tab" (or something similar). You can read more about opening tabs here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html

Comment: Hi i have found a solution in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html